# Creating a Progress Bar control that has multiple parts?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls, progress-bar

In C# .net, how can i created a custom Progress Bar control that will have multiple parts?
For instance 10 parts that I can update independently of each other, like if I need to change the progress of part 3 to 100 percent, that piece will look full and the other 9 will still look empty.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you tile ten normal progress bars?

Comment: No, I want a custom control, I can use.

Comment: Use `LayoutTable` and regular `ProgressBar`s, and save them in a list. The control should wrap that.

Comment: can you explain how it would look/act different than just having 10 progress bars?

Comment: Winforms, and it would allow me to see the value of them diffently, but act as a whole when it came to percentage. Meaning if we had 3 out of 10 at 100% the actual value of the bar would be 30 percent.

Comment: "the actual value"? where is this actual value and what is this actual value? I mean how is the actual value presented to the user? after all it matters only for the user, not the developer

Answer (score 0):

Put ten ProgressBars in your user control, one next to the other.